# How to show mathematical proficiency?

Tags: phd, mathematics, application, undergraduate, economics

I am computer science graduate from India. My mathematical background in under-graduate was two semesters of multi-variable calculus. I worked as a researcher in a Data Mining firm where I worked on Algorithmic trading. During my Job, I, on the side, learned Linear Algebra, Probability, Statistics, Abstract Algebra and Topology and little of Advanced Number Theory.
I am planning to apply for Phd in Economics. While applying for universities, in the application instructions the universities ask for mathematical proficiency in Linear Algebra, Probability, Statistics, Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra, etc., using the courses I have taken in my under-graduation.
As my under-graduate degree never had such courses, I am stuck. Is there any way to show mathematical proficiency like online courses in Coursera/edX?
I have not applied for masters as all universities take under-graduates directly into PhD programs provided they show mathematical proficiency and have decent GRE score, among other things.
Please provide me a way to show the universities that I am mathematical proficient as I have aced every other criteria required by the universities.
Are there any recognized standard tests that I can take to show my proficiency?

Edit: The universities I have contacted have categorically stated that GRE Math Subject test is not preferred.

Comment: It sounds like you have some non-trivial job experience, meaning that you're probably not a traditional student and some of the traditional student rules will not apply to you. Get in contact with the graduate admissions director at your desired departments directly and explain that you have acquired these skills through your work experience, and you don't have undergraduate course credit. They will definitely have some policy stating what your options are in this case.